# errors while building the android source code

Tags: android

I am trying to build the android source code in ubuntu 13.10, but I got so many errors
I have solved some of them then I got stucked . Now I want your help to build the android  source code,

before to that I will tell my system specification :
I am using Pentium D machine with 4 GB RAM with 50 GB free space in hard drive 
 using ubuntu 13.10 which is of 64 bit OS

And what are the packages I have installed

```
Python 2.7.5+, GNU Make 3.81, java version "1.6.0_45"
```

And I have followed the procedure for build such as :

1. G41M-Combo:~/bin/source $  : source build/envsetup.sh
2. G41M-Combo:~/bin/source $  : lunch
3. G41M-Combo:~/bin/source $  : 13
4. G41M-Combo:~/bin/source $   : make -j3

in 4th step i am using pentium D machine it is of 2 core so i have tried make -j2 also
but i did not got much difference 
i am attaching the errors which i got

```
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE manta
host C: acp <= build/tools/acp/acp.c
host C++: libhost <= build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp
host C: libhost <= build/libs/host/CopyFil`enter code here`e.c
i686-linux-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
i686-linux-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/pseudolocalize.o] Error 1
i686-linux-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/CopyFile.o] Error 1
```

your help will be greatly appretiated to me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need the c/c++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Never noticed about version of required compiler gcc for old androids from articles' google, so you must have installed gcc-4.4 and g++-4.4, g++-4.4-multilib, zlib1g-dev, openjdk-6-jre

After installed those, so then type export CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.4" and CXX="/usr/bin/g++-4.4", and make sure to use version of java 6 by typing

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
update-alternatives --config jar
```

Have fun for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You need C/C++ compiler for this to work, as I understand from error messages. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```